# Are .deb binary files?

Tags: debian, exe, deb

I know on linux they do not have .exe files, instead of that, some distributions like ubuntu have .deb files.
Are .deb binary files? What do they contain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

.deb is the debian software package format. It is used by debian and debian based distributions like ubuntu to provide and install software.

It contains two tar archives. One archive holds control information and the other the binaries of the software.

So .deb files contain binary files but those are not equivalent to the general windows .exe files.

There are similar files for other distributions for example .rpm for redhat.

Answer (score 2):

There are two types of files in *.deb. They are regular archives and control archives.You can try some commands.

```
dpkg-deb -I <deb>　# show the information of *.deb 
dpkg-deb -c <deb>  # list regular files of *.deb
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It is binary file but you can not run it. It is debian software package format that contains files of a software and allows you install a software. It is also a kind of archive file. Means you can see its content by opening it archive manager.

This command installs a .deb package

```
dpkg -i foo.deb
```

Answer (score 0):

.deb is a binary file. It include program to be installed + control file information

dpkg -c  package-version-revision_all.deb   ---> to view the content of .deb

### .deb contains

1) control.tar.gz -> control, md5sums, maintainers script ,conffiles

2) debian_binary (binary format)

3) data.tar.gz -> path of file to be installed